# Search: Make 2010 Search Scope work in 2013?

Tags: 2013, search, search-scope

I have successfully consumed a published SharePoint 2013 Search Service Application in my 2010 Farm. However my 2010 Search Scope no longer works... and you can't create Search Scopes in 2013.

So, how do I configure my 2013 farm to mimic the search scope? I'm not sure if this would be a Result Source or a Query Rule... I've used the same name for both and it still doesn't work, so I'm now trying a full crawl.

---

Update for Matt:

My 2010 scope is very simple scope:

- "ABC Guide". Rules:
- `Folder = http://server/business/guide [Include].`
- ContentSource = ABC Portal [Require].

My 2010 search results web part is here:

[image]

As I say, in 2013, I have an "ABC Guide" result source (and Query Rule for testing):
 - `Query Transform: {searchTerms} path:"http://server/business/guide"`

Interestingly, the People Search Core Results Web Part (which works in 2010-->2013)doesn't define a Scope in its "Location Properties". Somehow it must apply its filtering another way?

---

The actual error I get is: "Scope in your query does not exist".

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the Search Scope within the SharePoint 2010 Site Collection.  The scope definition will get shipped to the SP2013 service application and compiled there.  So far I've only defined Scopes that limited the result set by folder.  The drop-down for properties in a property-based scope isn't populated for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would use a Result Source. Can you tell me what rules you used in 2010 and maybe I can help you with the logic for a 2013 Result Source.

Comment: Thanks Matthew - I've added the details above. As I say, People search works, but it doesn't seem to define a scope in the results web part (must do it another way).

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you are trying to do this from 2010 on a 2013 SSA. I don't think the 2010 Web Part has the features. It's probably going to pass a scope, but you need a Result Source. If you are going to stay in 2010 you will probably have to customize the control so that it passes a query 2013 can understand.

Comment: I have a result source in 2013, but it doesn't appear in 2010 when I cut-over the search (in the proxy group).